# how to handle a carousel using 'useState' hook in nextJs 13

Tags: react-hooks, carousel, next.js13

I'm struggling to update some of the functions from a old version of nextjs to the new one (13).
Specially those containing the usestate hook. For some, i used the 'use client' as suggested by the documentation. But it's not working here. It's a carousel, calling an api for its data. How can i manage to replace the react 'usestate' hook or make it work ?
Thanks

```
import {getSliders} from "../../sanity/sanity-utils";
import {getHomeBanners} from "../../sanity/sanity-utils";
import {getSocios} from "../../sanity/sanity-utils";
import {useState} from "react";
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

export default async function Banner() {
    const homebanners = await getHomeBanners();
    const sliders = await getSliders();
    const socios = await getSocios();

    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = (index) => {
        setCurrentIndex(index);
    };

    return (
        <section className="promo">
            {sliders.length && (
                <>
                    <div className="promo-slider">
                        <div className="promo-slider__item promo-slider__item--style-2" style={{width: '100%', display: 'inline-block'}}>
                            <picture>
                                <Image src={sliders[currentIndex].image} alt={sliders[currentIndex].name} className="img--bg"/>
                            </picture>
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-xl-7">
                                        <div className="align-container">
                                            <div className="align-container__item">
                                                <div className="promo-slider__wrapper-1">
                                                    <h2 className="promo-slider__title"><span>{sliders[currentIndex].title}</span></h2>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="promo-slider__wrapper-2">
                                                    <p className="promo-slider__subtitle">{sliders[currentIndex].subtitle}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="promo-slider__wrapper-3">
                                                    <Link className="button promo-slider__button button--primary" href={sliders[currentIndex].link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" >{sliders[currentIndex].linktext}</Link>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="slider__nav slider__nav--promo">
                        <div className="promo-slider__count"/>
                        <div className="slider__arrows">
                            <div className="slider__prev" onClick={() => handleClick(currentIndex === 0 ? sliders.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1)}><i className="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"/></div>
                            <div className="slider__next" onClick={() => handleClick(currentIndex === sliders.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1)}><i className="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"/></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}

            <ul className="promo-socials">
                {socios.map((social) => (
                    <li className="promo-socials__item" key={social.title}>
                        <Link className="promo-socials__link" href={social.link}>{social.imgurl ? <img className="social-banner" src={urlFor(social.imgurl)} alt={social.title}/> : ''}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>

            {homebanners.map((banner, index) => (
                <div className="promo-pannel" key={banner.id + index}>
                    <Link className="anchor promo-pannel__anchor" href="#about">
                        <span>Scroll Down</span>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="promo-pannel__video">
                        <Image className="img--bg" src={banner.image} alt={banner.title}/>
                        <Link className="video-trigger" href={banner.videolink} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" >
                            <span>Watch our last video</span>
                            <i className="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="promo-pannel__phones">
                        <p className="promo-pannel__title">Phone numbers</p>
                        <Link className="promo-pannel__link" href="tel:+180012345678">{banner.phone}</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="promo-pannel__email">
                        <p className="promo-pannel__title">Email</p>
                        <Link className="promo-pannel__link" href="mailto:support@helpo.org">{banner.email}</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}

        </section>
    );
};
```

i tried "use client" at the top of my file, above my imports.